# How to call ember-cli build from gulp?

Tags: gulp, ember-cli

Is it possible to build Ember app for production from a separate gulpfile.js?

Both ember-cli and gulp are Node.js applications so in theory I should be able to create JavaScript code equivalent to

```
ember build --environment=production
```